# Where and how does libUV interact with code on node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, libuv

I wondered a question: "where and how does libUV interact with code on node.js". Lately I was investigating streams, also I read source on github.

Well, let's take source of script called as [`destroy.js`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/2b32985c626b57d7ea3e68d6ce088ea3183e3a58/lib/internal/streams/destroy.js). This script is responding for the destruction of streams: `stream.destroy()`. After that operation:

- in function [destroy](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/2b32985c626b57d7ea3e68d6ce088ea3183e3a58/lib/internal/streams/destroy.js#L39) are set states for streams into values:

  - `writable._stateWritable.destroyed = true`
  - `readable._stateReadable.destroyed = true`
- in function [_destroy](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/2b32985c626b57d7ea3e68d6ce088ea3183e3a58/lib/internal/streams/destroy.js#L77) are set states for streams into values:

  - `writable._stateWritable.closed = true`
  - `readable._stateReadable.closed = true`
- in funtion [emitCloseNT](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/2b32985c626b57d7ea3e68d6ce088ea3183e3a58/lib/internal/streams/destroy.js#L120):

  - sets value `writable._stateWritable.closeEmmited = true`
  - sets value `readable._stateReadable.closeEmmited = true`
  - emmits event `close`

That's all. Where and how does libUV interact with `stream.destroy()`? Even documentation of node about [writable.destroy](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#writabledestroyerror) says:

> This is a destructive and immediate way to destroy a stream

But what is it really? I see only the process of setting state for the streams and only it. So, where does libUV actually destroy stream?

Comment: libuv is just a "event loop" and not a js interpreter. The code that you linked is interpreted from v8.

Comment: @Marc you've not surprised me. My point is understand how code that I presented  interconnect with libUV mechanism, particulary how destroy.js really destroy stream with libUV

Comment: Ughm i **think** streams here a bad example, because the can be entirely  written in js. You should inspect the net/dgram module. Network sockets can not be done in js and need some syscalls from the os to work. I think that would be a better approach. Also, in my opinion you should more look into the c/c++ code than js. Just my 2 cents. :)

Comment: @Marc I also think that streams may be written without operation system calls. Thats why in fs module I saw loader bindings for C++ modules

Comment: isn't streams are specific to OS not libuv.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a subject matter expert, but after debugging the following code, I got a rough idea of what happens behind the scenes:

```js
var cnt = 0;
new stream.Readable({
  read(size) {
    if (++cnt > 10) this.destroy();
    this.push(String(cnt));
  }
}).pipe(process.stdout);
```

Upon `this.destroy()`, the `readableState.destroyed` is set to `true` [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/2b32985c626b57d7ea3e68d6ce088ea3183e3a58/lib/internal/streams/destroy.js#L62), and because of this the following `this.push("11")` returns `false` [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/2b32985c626b57d7ea3e68d6ce088ea3183e3a58/lib/internal/streams/readable.js#L286-L287). If `readableState.destroyed` had been `false`, it would instead have called `addChunk`, which would have ensured that reading goes on by emitting a `readable` event and calling `maybeReadMore` (see [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/2b32985c626b57d7ea3e68d6ce088ea3183e3a58/lib/internal/streams/readable.js#L312-L337)).

If the readable stream was created by `fs.createReadStream`, then the [`_destroy`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/2b32985c626b57d7ea3e68d6ce088ea3183e3a58/lib/internal/fs/streams.js#L282-L294) method additionally calls a [`close`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/2b32985c626b57d7ea3e68d6ce088ea3183e3a58/lib/fs.js#L525-L533)  method, which closes the file descriptor.

Comment: What has this todo with libuv and the binding between v8?

Comment: I've not given you bounty because it's not answer to my question, but I give you vote up for the last paragraph, this is important note.